# How to create a column that holds an array in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Background:

I am making a db for a reservartions calendar. The reservations are hourly based, so I need to insert many items to one column called "hours_reserved".

Example tables of what I need:

```
        Table "Space"
  Column        /          Values
 id             /             1
 date           /          5.2.2020
 hours          /      {  8-10, 10-12 }
```

---

```
        Table "reservation"
  Column        /          Values
 id             /             1
 space_id       /             1
 date           /          5.2.2020
 reserved_hours /            8-10
```

---

```
        Table "reservation"
  Column        /          Values
 id             /             2
 space_id       /             1
 date           /          5.2.2020
 hours          /           10-12
```

So I need to have multiple items inserted into "space" table "hours" column.
How do I do this in Postgres?
Also is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Read up on on database normalization and creating one-to-many relationships. While possible in Postgres, storing things in arrays is rarely the best choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more way to do this, depending on the type of the `hours` field (i.e. text[], json or jsonb) I'd go with jsonb just because you can do a lot of things with it and you'll find this experience to be useful in the short term.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."space" 
("id" SERIAL, "date_schedule" date, "hours" jsonb, PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

Whenever you insert a record in this table that's manually crafted, write it as text (single quoted json object) and cast it to jsonb

```
insert into "space" 
  (date_schedule,hours) 
values 
  ('05-02-2020'::date, '["8-10", "10-12"]'::jsonb);
```

[image]

There is more than one way to match these available hours against the reservations and you can take a look at the docs, on the [json and jsonb operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). For example, doing:

```
 SELECT id,date_schedule, jsonb_array_elements(hours) hours FROM "public"."space"
```

would yield

[image]

Which has these ugly double quotes (which is correct, since json can hold several kinds of scalars, that column is polimorfic :D)

However, you can perform a little transformation to remove them and be able to perform a join with `reservations`

```
with unnested as (
  SELECT id,date_schedule, jsonb_array_elements(hours) hours FROM "public"."space"
)
select id,date_schedule,replace(hours::text, '"','') from unnested
```

[image]

The same can be achieved defining the field as text[] (the insertion syntax is different but trivial)

in that scenario your data will look like:

[image]

Which you can unwrap as:

```
SELECT id,date_schedule, unnest(hours) FROM "public"."space"
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. Do I need to specify anything when creating a node endpoint for this table?

Comment: most ORMs will deal seamlessly with javascript objects. IF you plan tu use just a driver, go for PG Promise

Comment: I decided to test with text[]. Any Idea why using put with postman returns     "message": "error: invalid input syntax for type integer: \"{\"hours\":[\"8-10\"]}\""?

Comment: Don't know, but if you're using say, express to handle the request, console.log them to see what's coming. Perhaps you're not using the json parsing middleware?

Comment: Yes content type is JSON. My endpoint is like this `// UPDATE
exports.updateVaraus = async(id, myarray) => {
    try {
        const result = await client.query('UPDATE varaus SET id =1$, myarray = $2') 
        [id, myarray]
        );
        return result.rows
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD COLUMN myarray text[];
```

Works fine.

I got a following problem when trying to put(update) into that column using postman(create works fine):

```
{
    "myarray": ["8-10"]
}
```

Results into:

> "message": "error: invalid input syntax for type integer:
>   \"{\"myarray\":[\"8-10\"]}\""